# cookie store json string

Tags: json, django, string, cookies

I'm trying to store a json string in a cookie.
I use `JSON.stringify` to convert json object to a json string.

My json look something like:

```
var obj = {1: ['a', 'b']};
```

I use `getCookie` and `setCookie` found in this w3schools page:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

When I set the cookie, not only it does not work when I try to retrieve it, it also messes up other cookies I have like my sessionid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sessionStorage:

```
 var obj = {1: ['a', 'b']};
 sessionStorage.setItem('obj', JSON.stringify(obj));
 var obj = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.obj);
```

Comment: or local storage, or.., but this is not really what the question asks. It looks like Django cant out of the box support this (ie json in cookies). Session storage has different characteristics to that of cookies, so although this may help some users, its not a complete answer